# Converting a column (of a dplyr tbl-object) into tbl-header

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a `data.frame` as follows:

```
     types       long_name
     (chr)           (chr)
1  neighborhood Upper East Side
2  sublocality  Manhattan
3  postal_code  10021
```

I want to transform it as follows:

```
     neighborhood    sublocality   postal_code
     (chr)           (chr)         (chr)
1  Upper East Side   Manhattan     10021
```

There has to be a quick and easy way of doing this.

Editors note: This is displayed, not as an R dataframe, but as a dply tbl-object:

```
dput(as.tbl(dfrm))
structure(list(types = c("neighborhood", "sublocality", "postal_code"
), long_name = c("Upper East Side", "Manhattan", "10021")), .Names = c("types", 
"long_name"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: dplyr-`tbl`'s appear to be the new `data.table`'s in the sense that noobs often mistake them for actual R dataframes. I think the more knowledgeable useRs need to maintain some clarity in object class awareness.

Comment: @42- my apologies, will be more careful next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sticking with the Hadleyverse, we could use `tidyr::spread` to move from long to wide:

```
library(tidyr)

df %>% spread(types, long_name)
# Source: local data frame [1 x 3]
# 
#      neighborhood postal_code sublocality
#             (chr)       (chr)       (chr)
# 1 Upper East Side       10021   Manhattan
```

Comment: Oh sure, show everybody up why don't you ;)  @Armin - I'd probably check this one instead.  It's more in line with what you're working on.

Answer (score 2):

Set `types` as the names on the `long_name` vector then run `as.data.frame.list()` on it. Assuming `df` is your data frame ...

```
as.data.frame.list(
    with(df, setNames(long_name, types)), 
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
#      neighborhood sublocality postal_code
# 1 Upper East Side   Manhattan       10021
```

Or, the same thing a slightly different way ...

```
as.data.frame(
    with(df, setNames(as.list(long_name), types)),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

And if you need a numeric postal code, run `as.numeric()` on that column.  Also, since you are using *dplyr*, you can get to your exact desire result by wrapping this in `tbl_df()`.  Or you could do it all in *dplyr* with something like

```
df %>%
    do(
        as.data.frame.list(
            setNames(.$long_name, .$types), 
            stringsAsFactors = FALSE
        )
    ) %>%
    tbl_df
# Source: local data frame [1 x 3]
#
#      neighborhood sublocality postal_code
#             (chr)       (chr)       (chr)
# 1 Upper East Side   Manhattan       10021
```

**Data:**

```
df <- structure(list(types = c("neighborhood", "sublocality", "postal_code"
), long_name = c("Upper East Side", "Manhattan", "10021")), .Names = c("types", 
"long_name"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: I appeared to be a dplyr `tbl`.

Comment: Got it coverered @42-

Answer (score 2):

We can use `transpose`

```
library(data.table)
setNames(transpose(df[-1]), df$types)
#     neighborhood sublocality postal_code
#1 Upper East Side   Manhattan       10021
```